# How do I download a password protected shared file from SharePoint using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

So I am working to attempt to leverage a corporate SharePoint as file repo for non-critical files that are downloaded via PowerShell scripts. For security purposes I can't use a dedicated M365 account to access the files in SharePoint. However I know I can password protect a shared file that is made available to anyone that has the URL. Right now I have a dedicated site setup in SharePoint and the testing file has been shared out and password protected, however the cmdlet I am using (`Invoke-WebRequest`) doesn't seem to allow for a password to be passed to the URL for access to the file. There is no username as the file is shared with anyone who has the link. I have tested the process without the password applied and the script works great, but I need to be able to have the password in play and access/download the file via PowerShell. My current script is beow. Is anyone familiar with a way to make this work?

```
$url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/x/site/random_string&download=1"
$dest = "C:\folder\file.ext"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest
```

I did try and add `&password=<password>` but that was a no go.

Comment: I think you should consider using the Pnp Framework to try to accomplish your objective. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets

https://github.com/pnp/powershell/releases/tag/v2.2.0

Comment: Thanks for the help in direction on this @GlennFerrie. I did find another avenue of information, leveraging F12 tools in the browser. I'll post more on this when I sanitize some code I have. I'm interested in getting community input on my processes.